# Cast filestream length to int

Tags: c#, casting, filestream

I have a question about the safety of a cast from long to int. I fear that the method I wrote might fail at this cast. Can you please take a look at the code below and tell me if it is possible to write something that would avoid a possible fail?

Thank you in advance.

```
    public static string ReadDecrypted(string fileFullPath)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileFullPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            int fsLength = (int)fs.Length;
            byte[] decrypted;
            byte[] read = new byte[fsLength];
            if (fs.CanRead)
            {
                fs.Read(read, 0, fsLength);
                decrypted = ProtectedData.Unprotect(read, CreateEntropy(), DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);
                result = Utils.AppDefaultEncoding.GetString(decrypted, 0, decrypted.Length);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Why not just declare fsLength as long and avoid the cast?

Comment: I'm not an expert in C#, but suppose `fs.Length` equals 2 to the 31st power (1 << 31). Will your cast result in a negative number for `fsLength`?

Comment: You can also question the safety of pouring the contents of a two-litre bottle into a one-litre bottle without checking if the source bottle is more than half-full. The end result would roughly be the same.

Comment: @Yahia -sorry I was not clear initially, I cast because filestream.Read() requires an int as the last parameter and not long

Comment: @Tod - because I can't call filestream.Read() with a long parameter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the short answer is: yes, this way you will have problems with any file with a length >= 2 GB!

if you don't expect any files that big then you can insert directly at the start of the using block:

```
if (((int)fs.Length) != fs.Length) throw new Exception ("too big");
```

otherwise you should NOT cast to int, but change `byte[] read = new byte[fsLength];`
 to `byte[] read = new byte[fs.Length];` and use a loop to read the file content in "chunks" of max. 2 GB per chunk.

Another alternative (available in .NET4) is to use MemoryMappedFile (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx) - this way you don't need to call Read at all :-)

Answer (score 3):

Well, `int` is 32-bit and `long` is 64-bit, so there's always the possibility of losing some data with the cast if you're opening up 2GB files; on the other hand, that allocation of a byte array of `fsLength` would seem to indicate you're not expecting files that big.  Put a check in to make sure that `fs.Length` isn't greater than 2,147,483,647, and you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer; I understand that I should avoid the cast if I was to expect bigger files. How could I call filestream.Read() on such big files, could you provide a hint on that?

Comment: You can just call filestream.Read(), just don't read the whole file at one time; read one chunk, handle that chunk, then read the next chunk.